# Laravel Socialite With Apple return "Invalid JWT Signature"

Tags: php, ios, laravel, laravel-socialite

I try to use provided token to fetch current user data as API but I keep received error "Invalid JWT Signature". I had follow different tutorials like [bannister](https://bannister.me/blog/generating-a-client-secret-for-sign-in-with-apple-on-each-request) AND [devpeel](https://devpeel.com/implement-apple-sign-in-with-laravel/) but both also giving me the same error. I'm using Laravel 9 and the socialite package is 5.5. May I know is there anyway to solve this?

Generate client secret by Ruby

```
require "jwt"

key_file = "key.txt"
team_id = "team_id"
client_id = "client_id"
key_id = "key_id"
validity_period = 180 # In days. Max 180 (6 months) according to Apple docs.

private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new IO.read key_file

token = JWT.encode(
 {
   iss: team_id,
   iat: Time.now.to_i,
   exp: Time.now.to_i + 86400 * validity_period,
   aud: "https://appleid.apple.com",
   sub: client_id
 },
 private_key,
  "ES256",
   header_fields=
   {
    kid: key_id 
   }
)
puts token
```

Generate client secret by PHP

```
// Generate client secret in php
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

    public function createToken()
{
    $teamId = 'team_id';

    $keyId = 'key_id';

    $sub = env('APPLE_CLIENT_ID');

    $aud = 'https://appleid.apple.com'; // it's a fixed URL value

    $iat = strtotime('now');

    $exp = strtotime('+60days');

    $keyContent = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../../../key.txt');

    

    echo JWT::encode([

        'iss' => $teamId,

        'iat' => $iat,

        'exp' => $exp,

        'aud' => $aud,

        'sub' => $sub,

    ], $keyContent, 'ES256', $keyId);

}
```

Access by token

```
public function socialMediaLogin($request)
{
   $social = Socialite::driver($request->provider)->userFromToken($request->token);
   print_r($social);
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should not call `env()` directly. It does not get cached. You should create a config entry somewhere for it. Maybe in `config/services.php`.

Comment: @IGP thanks for advice and I will take care of that but do you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem a month ago on my project, and the biggest problem for me was misunderstanding the whole flow, because I'm experienced in PHP(Laravel), but not so much in iOS.

So, at first, we should get auth results on mobile side. It should look like this:

```
                case .success (let authResults):
                guard let credential = authResults.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential,
                      let identityToken = credential.identityToken,
                      let token = String(data: identityToken, encoding: .utf8),
                 // to use decode(jwt: token), you have to install JWTDecode package and import to this file!
                      let decodedToken = try? decode(jwt: token) else { return }
                // Send decodedToken.string to your backend
```

In your Laravel application, in config/services.php you should have apple credentials like this:

```
    'apple' => [
    'client_id' => env('APPLE_CLIENT_ID'),
    // your generated client_secret
    'client_secret' => env('APPLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env('APPLE_REDIRECT_URI')
],
```

In your controller, you can get user from sent(above) decodedToken

(decodedToken.string = $request->token actually):

```
        $social = Socialite::driver('apple')->userFromToken($request->token);
```

It worked for me. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: hi Andrija Antanaskovic really appreciate that your replied. So which means I need to decode the identity token before I pass to Laravel side?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. In the beginning I was sending identityToken in basic form to my backend, and I was getting the same error every time...After some time of research, I realized that I have to decode that token on mobile side first, and send it's string (decodedToken.string) to my backend. One more thing, I will update my answer above, because I forgot to add a note. Actually, you have to install JWTDecode package (iOS app) and import to certain file, and after that you will be able to use `decode(jwt: token)`. That's it! :)

Comment: woah... that's really rare compare to other providers
but really thanks for your help.
Just another question, I got success decode the identity token in Laravel and able to capture user's data, does it count as success to fetch user data or need to use Socialite again to get correct user data?

Comment: Yes, everything can be solved in several ways. I did it in my own way, and it works, so I wanted to share my experience with you  :)